# How do I remove a certificate from Certificate Trust Settings if the profile doesn't exist?

Tags: ios, security, certificate

If I go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings... I see several profiles installed under the "ENABLE FULL TRUST FOR ROOT CERTIFICATES" heading.

There is a way to toggle them off, but not disable them.

According to [this website](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/remove-unnecessary-profiles-certificates-your-iphone-protect-your-privacy-security-0193170/), it says that you can remove these certificates by navigating to Settings > General > Profiles. When I navigate there, I don't see any corresponding Profiles that are installed. They seem to have been deleted a while ago, yet the Certificates remain under Certificate Trust Settings.

[Another site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7946499) recommends to re-install the profile temporarily and then remove it. However, the profile is long gone and I don't know where to get it from.

How do I remove these certificates that don't have corresponding profiles on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on iOS 13.3. I tested this using non-orphaned certificates in hopes of isolating the issue to see what is the minimum option you can use to remove these certificates.

Works:

- Assuming you have the profile (i.e. non-orphaned): Settings > Profile > (Profile) > Remove
- Nuclear option (deleting everything on your phone): Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings

Doesn't work:

- Settings > General > Reset > Reset network settings
- Settings > General > Reset > Reset all settings

Comment: What is Settings > Profile?